# Calculating the sum in C++

Tags: c++

How do I calculate the sum to below in C++?
I tried the following code but failed.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, p, r = -1;
    cin >> n;
    for (p = 0; p < 10; p++)
        r *= (-1);
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's basic maths, it's `1*(10+1)`.

Comment: Why are you inputting *n*? Your expression says that *n* starts from 0 and goes to 10.

Comment: I suspect the sum should read sum( n=0, 10, (-1)^(n+1) ), so the result is either -1 or 0

Comment: that's still basic maths, no need for a loop, you just `-1 * upperLimit%2`

Comment: Look at the series and think: `-1 + 1 -1 +1 -1 +1 ...`

Comment: @Flavius is correct, there is no need for a loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int p, r = 1;
    int iSum=0;
    // cin >> n;

    for (p = 0; p <= 10; p++)
    {
        r *= (-1);
        iSum+=r;
    }
    cout << iSum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's basic mathematics, there is no need for a loop, you can just calculate `-1 * (upperLimit + 1)%2`.

Look at the series and think: `-1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 ...`.

Comment: +1 yes, in general it would be x * upperLimit % 2. Great answer!

Comment: @MRM, that would produce a positive 1 or a 0, depending on the upderLimit. The only possible sums are -1 or 0. 10 % 2 = 0, 0 * -1 = 0. 11 % 2 = 1, 1 * -1 = -1. I think this is in an old Calculus book of mine as a telescoping series. I'll verify.

Comment: While accurate, this doesn't apply to more complex examples.

Answer (score 1):

Although @Flavius is right, the sum starts from 0 so it'll be `-1 * (upperLimit+1)%2` as the sum iterates not 10 but 11 times. The `upperLimit%2` thing works for sums starting at 1

P.S: Sorry for answering, I cannot yet comment, just registered.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that but I was too lazy to fix it. +1 and welcome on SO.